# How can I make sure that they are at least one radio been click when submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, radiobuttonlist

Does anyone know how can I make sure that they are at least one radio been click when submit in C# .net?

I have the following code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="billingType" runat="server" CssClass="cl_billing_method"
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" data-messages="{required:'Billing methods is required'}">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Email" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Digital Mailbox" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Paper" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How can I validate it so that when submit button is been clicked and it will do the client check and show error if there have no radio button been selected?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Validate_Checkbox()
{
    var chks=document.getElementsByTagName('input');   
    var hasChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
    {
        if (chks[i].checked)
        {
            hasChecked = true;
            break;
        }
   }
   if (hasChecked == false)
   {
        alert("Please select at least one checkbox..!");

        return false;
   }

    return true;
}     
</script>
```

and on Submit Button you have to write

write

```
OnClientClick="return Validate_Checkbox()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Better option is use a `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` it will looks like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Billing methods is required"
 ControlToValidate="billingType" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validateBill"  />
```

Add `ValidationGroup` to the button:

```
<asp:Button Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validateBill"/>
```

If you are getting some error saying *"UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery' ..."* then add the following lines to the config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```